# Git Branching & merging workflow problems. How do you do it?

Tags: git, merge, workflow, branch

This is our development workflow:

1. Developer works on an issue in a new topic branch.
2. Once he is finished, he pushes the branch up for review.
3. I merge the branch into a develop branch and push it upstream on the staging server.
4. Client reviews the changes and approves / declines it.

My problem is at step 3 & 4. The client has access only on the staging server, so in order for him to see the changes I have to merge the topic branch into a develop branch and push it to the staging server and I usually don't merge only 1 branch, but on average 3 - 4.

If the client rejects the changes and he needs further modifications then the developer fixes the problems in the same topic branch and I have to remerge into develop.

By remerging a topic branch multiple times into develop I loose track of that issue in the history. (sometimes resulting in conflicts too)

Is this a 'healthy' development workflow? 
What are your suggestions, improvements?

Comment: Can the staging server handle multiple branches? If so, you can merge `develop` and `feature-x` into `develop-feature-x`, test that, then do the actual merge if it worked. (Or just push `feature-x` to staging.)

Comment: That's interesting... I would have to manually update the staging server, this way. Also, I don't know if this would complicate things or not...

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you mean in the last sentence. What do you mean by "you lose track of the issue" and which conflicts could result from more work done on the original branch?

Comment: The problem is merging multiple branches into develop. So for example if dev1 works on some files in branch1, merging into develop, dev2 works on branch2. There could be issues with same files being written into, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If the client rejects the changes and he needs further modifications then the developer fixes the problems in the same topic branch and I have to remerge into develop.

I would rather revert (as in [`git revert`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert)) the rejected change in the development branch, and wait for the developer's fix.
by using git revert, I only add new commits, instead of changing the history (with rebase or a `git reset`)

That way, the next commit (of the same feature) should be easily merged again in development branch.

Comment: I personally like the sound of this approach. It uses the git tool in the most intended of ways, minimizing unnecessary workaround branches. (Not that they are expensive, but it can get confusing and error-prone after a while.)

Comment: Doesn't git revert adds new commit to the history, instead of deleting the whole commit altogether? Why rebase isn't a good option in this case?

Comment: @feketegy yes, as I mention in my answer, `git revert` does add new commit. Avoiding rebase facilitate synchronization between repos (you only pull new commits, instead of resetting your branch because the upstream branch has changed), and will facilitate merging *again* a (fixed) feature.

Comment: Yes, but `git revert` will pollute the history this way. For example I see a commit, then I see a revert commit then again a commit. It's hard to review the files committed...

Comment: @feketegy pollute? It will only emphasize the rejected feature by the client. With the right naming convention, you can quickly extract the right commits to review.

Comment: @VonC what's your convention? :)

Comment: @feketegy simply "for review" for commits targeted for code review, and "rejected" for commits created by `git revert`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply introduce a staging branch, that is dirty and no one is allowed to ever branch of it.

- Make sure your staging deployment process handles history rewrites. If your staging server pulls from a central repo, replace the pull with a `fetch` and a `reset --hard origin/branch`
- Whenever you want a client to review a change, simply use your process from before – merge it in and if it needs changing, remerge.
- Merge in `develop` once in a while to make sure your have all it’s changes. If you are not currently having any reviews (=`staging` should be in sync with `develop`), reset `staging` to `develop` instead (`git checkout staging`; `git reset --hard develop`)
- As staging is supposed to be dirty, you can always do crazy rewriting, like just going back a few steps (`git reset --hard HEAD~4`) without consequences if a change broke something etc.
- Only merge your changes into develop once the client approved them.

This way, you won’t have to worry about producing a nice history in a process where you don’t really care about history (showing stuff to clients) and your `develop` branch gets a very clean history.

In case you are worried about a having to resolve merge conflicts multiple times, have a look at [git’s rerere feauture](http://git-scm.com/2010/03/08/rerere.html)

Comment: That is the opposite approach to my own answer, and presented like you do, it can work too. +1